# Jsoup remove nested tags but keep text

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have html in a set of elements so there may be other items like this

```
<b><a title="San Francisco/Twin Peaks-Lake Merced">Twin Peaks</a></b>
```

but I would like to clean it up with jsoup like this

```
<b>Twin Peaks</b>
```

Would using a whitelist be the best idea?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

sorry for cluttering up stackoverflow, but unwrap solves the problem.

```
document.select("a").unwrap()
```